# How do i do in godot to respawn my character after falling out of the map

Tags: godot

I am making a 2d game on godot engine and i want my player to respawn if he falls out of the map and i don't know how to do it!

I tried to see

```
if touched tile set:
 get_tree().reload_current_scene()
```

but it failed. I had tried to see if there is something about it in Godot docs but it's not and i tried to do it in godot by coding something like but it failed. I am expecting that my player after touching the tile set he repawns where the game begins.

Comment: you should continue on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you be most specific on "it failed"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure about how your godot scene/project is setup, so I'll tell you the way I usually do it in my godot projects. I'm assuming you are using godot 3.x.

At the bottom of the scene, put an Area2D node with a collision body. This is needed so that we know when the player falls off the map. Attach a script to this Area2D, and connect the "body_entered" signal to the script. Your Area2d script should look something like this:

```
extends Area2D

func _on_Area2D_body_entered(body):
    pass
```

Now we'll check if the body that hit the Area2d is the player; if it is, then we'll call a `respawn()` function on it

```
extends Area2D

func _on_Area2D_body_entered(body):
    if "Player" in body.name:
       body.respawn()
```

Now in your player script, define the respawn() function

```
func respawn():
    get_tree().reload_current_scene()
```

Now when the player falls out of the map, they will hit the Area2d, which triggers the respawn() function to be called, which reloads the current scene.